# SQL Custom Query for Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am trying to create a custom SQL query in tableau to create 2 fields and am a little stuck on how to do this. I want to create a field1 that is unanswered scores and field 2 that is max point differential during the game. The relevant data fields are game_id, drive_id, result(each result would have different score value), and team.

For field1 the logic in standard language would be for each game what are most scoring results that occur for one team over the other.

For field2 the logic in standard language would be turn the results into a points value and then find the score of the game for each team at the time of the drive. Drive id is in numerical order.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you give us some example input/output data?

Comment: It is almost always a better (and faster) strategy to learn to use the Tableau features to achieve your result that to use custom SQL. There was a time when custom SQL was needed for some situations because there wasn't an alternative in Tableau, but today there are only a few very specialized situations where it is needed.

Comment: Describe your problem more clearly, and determine next whether you need custom SQL or a different Tableau feature to address it.